# MySQL Database Load of Add Column with Default vs. Add Column and Leaving Null

Tags: mysql, sql, migration

Consider the two SQL statements.

`ALTER TABLE books ADD COLUMN num_sold int DEFAULT 0`

versus

`ALTER TABLE books ADD COLUMN num_sold int`

The general idea is, in one case we set a default value, in the next we just let it start as NULL.

Will the database load be significantly higher for the version with the default value? More generally, I'm wondering what happens 'under the hood' differently for these two cases -- what has to change on disk, what locking is created and for how long, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help if you realize that leaving out a default is the same as `default null`.

When you set the values in a record, all the values are set at the same time.  Whether the values are provided (in the `insert`/`load` mechanism) or determined from metadata is going to a very negligible difference in terms of performance.  This is not something that you should worry about.